# AttributeError: object 'int' does not have attribute

Tags: python

```
class RomanNumerals():

    def __init__(self,number):
        self.num = number

    def from_roman(self):
        int_num=0
        rom = {'I':1, 'V':5, 'X':10, 'L':50, 'C':100, 'D':500, 'M':1000}
        i=0
        while (i<len(self.num)):
            if(i+1==len(self.num)):
                int_num+=rom[self.num[i]]
                break
            else:
                if (rom[self.num[i]]<rom[self.num[i+1]]):
                    int_num+=rom[self.num[i+1]]-rom[self.num[i]]
                    i+=2
                else:
                    int_num+=rom[self.num[i]]
                    i+=1
        return int_num

    def to_roman(self):
        val = (1000, 900,  500, 400, 100,  90, 50,  40, 10,  9,   5,  4,   1)
        syb = ('M',  'CM', 'D', 'CD','C', 'XC','L','XL','X','IX','V','IV','I')
        roman_num = ""
        for i in range(len(val)):
            count = int(self.num / val[i])
            roman_num += syb[i]*int(count)
            self.num -= val[i] * count
        return roman_num
```

I call `RomanNumerals.to_roman (1000)` - it gives an error:

```
AttributeError: object 'int' does not have attribute 'num'
```

My code does not pass the test, although everything works for me. Tell me please where to dig to figure it out.

Comment: Your `to_roman` method is missing an argument to pass in the value `1000`.

Answer (score 0):

If you call `RomanNumerals.to_roman (1000)` then you're passing 1000 as `self`. But `self` is expected to be an instance of your class.

`to_roman` is an instance method, and you should call it on an instance of your class.

```
r = RomanNumerals(1000)
print(r.to_roman())
```

(Though I note in `from_roman` that you seem to expect `self.num` to be a string or a list, which is not consistent with the way you treat it in `to_roman`.)

Alternatively, if you just to use `to_roman` as a standalone function, then you should drop the class and write `to_roman` to accept an argument as a plain int.

Answer (score 0):

I understand this very well, so I checked the class’s performance. This is a task for Codewars, and in tests there is such testing:

```
RomanNumerals.to_roman (1000)
```

Answer (score 0):

I understand that it is easier to write a function for this task, but the task states that you need to write a class and testing takes place through such a strange request.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. Here is the code for my question:

```
class RomanNumerals():

    def from_roman(num_rom):
        int_num=0
        rom = {'I':1, 'V':5, 'X':10, 'L':50, 'C':100, 'D':500, 'M':1000}
        i=0
        while (i<len(num_rom)):
            if(i+1==len(num_rom)):
                int_num+=rom[num_rom[i]]
                break
            else:
                if (rom[num_rom[i]]<rom[num_rom[i+1]]):
                    int_num+=rom[num_rom[i+1]]-rom[num_rom[i]]
                    i+=2
                else:
                    int_num+=rom[num_rom[i]]
                    i+=1
        return int_num

    def to_roman(num_ar):
        val = (1000, 900,  500, 400, 100,  90, 50,  40, 10,  9,   5,  4,   1)
        syb = ('M',  'CM', 'D', 'CD','C', 'XC','L','XL','X','IX','V','IV','I')
        roman_num = ""
        for i in range(len(val)):
            count = int(num_ar / val[i])
            roman_num += syb[i]*int(count)
            num_ar -= val[i] * count
        return roman_num

print(RomanNumerals.to_roman(1000))
```

I did not expect that they would begin to minus me. This site seems to be created to help and explain to less qualified people ...

Answer (score 0):

Much more elegant way of solving:

```
class Solution(object):
    def romanToInt(self, s):
        """
        :type s: str
        :rtype: int
        """
        roman = {'I':1,'V':5,'X':10,'L':50,'C':100,'D':500,'M':1000,'IV':4,'IX':9,'XL':40,'XC':90,'CD':400,'CM':900}
        i = 0
        num = 0
        while i < len(s):
            if i+1<len(s) and s[i:i+2] in roman:
                num+=roman[s[i:i+2]]
                i+=2
            else:
                #print(i)
                num+=roman[s[i]]
                i+=1
        return num
ob1 = Solution()
print(ob1.romanToInt("III"))
print(ob1.romanToInt("CDXLIII"))
```